# Output last 10 news use django-sidebar

Tags: python, django, templates, widget, sidebar

I use django-sidebar(https://github.com/ekaputra07/django-sidebar) for building my widgets. I know how I can use a simple variables, however now I cannot use objects for receive data.
Below I providing my code (file django_latest_posts.py as example):

```
from sidebar.base import SidebarWidget, sidebar_widget
from django import forms
from news.models import Post


TEMPLATE = """
<div class="last_posts">
{% for post in posts %}
   <div>{{post}}</div>
{% endfor %}
 </div>
"""

#TEMPLATE = get_template('latest_posts_widget.html')



class TextForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    posts = BlogPost.objects.all()[:2]  # I need to show last two posts


class LatestPosts(SidebarWidget):
    #admin_form = TextForm
    #template_text = get_template('latest_posts_widget.html')
    template_text = TEMPLATE

# register the Widget
sidebar_widget = LatestPosts('Latest Posts','Display a Latest Posts')
```

Please help me how I would correct receive data in TEMPLATE?
Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom template tags to achieve this. the most appropriate ones seem to be [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) (but it's worth reading the whole chapter!). 
There is a good step-by-step instruction which should work for you.